# delete nth of lines using awk

Tags: unix, sed, awk

At a set interval of records, I need to remove 4 lines/records.  Can this be done with awk or sed.

I have a file that has a form feed character every 70th record.  This is causing a blank line to be printed in my output.

I want to use awk or sed do delete the four (4) lines before the form feed so my page is now 66 lines long.

That should eliminate my blank pages.

The file I am passing is several thousand records in a spool file and I was hoping for an easy solution.  I've tried

```
sed -n -e '65~68p;
```

but I don't think I have that available on my unix box because I get an error when I try running that command.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '{if ((NR%70) <65) print $0;}' inputfile
```

should do the job.

Comment: `awk '(NR%70) <65' inputfile`

Comment: I need a little more help please.  I don't quite understand the syntax.  I understand how the NR%70 works but what does it mean when you add the <65 after that?  Is that telling me to delete lines 66 - 70?  Sorry, I'm rather new to awk & unix.  How does it know to delete those lines - there is no delete statement?

Comment: `nr%70` gives as result n modulo 70, that is 0..69 depending on the actual record-number. then its checked wether this is less than 65 . if thats true, then the statement (`print $0`) is executed. So there are no lines deleted, just the input file is processed, and the output of this program does not contain the lines 66-70. This output you can then store in another file instead of displaying it in the terminal with `awk '{if ((NR%70) <65) print $0;}' inputfile>anotherfile`

Answer (score 0):

pbhd gave a nice solution before I managed to post mine, but here it is in case you'd like to do it using python:

```
    import sys
    s = sys.stdin.read()
    for page in s.split('\f'):
        lines = page.splitlines()
        print '\n'.join(lines[:-4]) + '\f'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 'H;g;s:[^\n]::g;/.\{64\}/{N;N;N;s:.::g; x;s:\n::p;d};${x;s:\n::;p};d' FILE
```

This line will remove the next 3 lines after the line 65, 65*2, ..., 65*K .

If you want to remove more than 3 lines, add more N;N;N;.

Comment: wouldn't this only delete the third and fourht lines of my file?  I need it to delete lines throughout my file.  for example, i need the 67, 68 & 69 line deleted and then again after another 67 lines have been read, delete three more lines.